# asp button interrupts with Bootstrap dialog popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make few buttons which are asp buttons and when the user clicks, it shows a dialog pop.

So here is what I have done till now:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Req" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>
```

The problem is `runat="server"`. When the runat server is there, the dialog opens and closes very fast like a blink due to postback if I'm not mistake. Is there any workaround for this? Or any suggestions how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would update your HTML so that the "Save changes" button is the asp button and the `data-toggle="modal"` button is just a normal html button.

This way the bootstrap functionality will work, then when you click "Save changes", your .net button will take over the Postback and functionality.

Effectively this is what your "Save changes" button is doing, and your current asp button is just opening the modal.

Comment: my problem is toggling the dialog box. the button1. okay the scenario is like this: i have 12 products with 12 requirements button which each is supposed to trigger the dialog box and pulls the appropriate requirements data from an xml table for the product that the button was clicked. right now the dialog box does not even show up. when i use anchor tag it works fine and it show the dialog box but i dont know which button is clicked to pull the appropriate data from xml table. now im lost and im not sure what im supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the *asp:button*, and update the standard button like this...

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                          onClick="CodeBehindMethodName">Save changes</button>

 protected void CodeBehindMethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ...
 }
```

Comment: my problem is not save button...my problem is button1 and triggering the dialog box as it does not popup at all